# How to make Cypress wait for .intercept requests to finish?

Tags: async-await, cypress

### Code:

```js
describe("Cypress", () => {
  it("Example Test", () => {
    cy.intercept("GET", "/api/**").as("getApi");
    cy.visit("/home/");
    cy.wait("@getApi");
    console.log("here");
  });
});
```

#### Output:

```
here
Request Finished: /api/1/
Request Finished: /api/2/
```

Is there a way to make Cypress wait for the requests it intercepts to finish before continuing?

##### Desired Output:

```
Request Finished: /api/1/
Request Finished: /api/2/
here
```

*Note: Page Code*

```js
$.get(url).done(function (response) {
  console.log("Request Finished", this.url);
});
```

Comment: Cypress runs through all the commands to queue them up before starting the test. If you want to run code after the request has been waited for, look at the example: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Wait-for-a-specific-request-to-respond. See also https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Closures.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you @jonrsharpe